# Deployed Polymer app on Firebase shows empty page

Tags: polymer-1.0, firebase-hosting

I built my polymer project and deployed it with the firebase command. I followed the instruction on the polymer site. In Chrome on my Mac it works, but on my mobile(Chrome and Safari) and Safari on my Mac it display an empty page.
Can anybody help me out?
best regards

Comment: I am having the same problem. While it works in Chrome I am getting a syntax error in Firefox on PC, IE 11 on PC, and Safari on Mac.  It says "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' for bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js

Comment: I have just logged a bug here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3882

Comment: Thanks to your bug report i found de solution. My Polymer.json is okay but if i build my app with the polymer build command, the pollyfill will not be included in the build folder. I added it manually and now it works.

Comment: See my answer below.  I did more research and found that this is a known issue with all dependencies.  See the link to the other bug I found.

Comment: This problem has just been fixed with v0.16.0.  Take the latest version with: `npm i -g polymer-cli`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: the dependency problem has been fixed with v0.16.0 which deployed this evening 8/24/2016.  I have kept the below workaround just for reference.**

---

This is a known issue: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/347

includeDependencies stipulated in polymer.json is not being processed.

Here's the remedy for now:

The 'polymer build' process is not including the polyfill in the build even when you include it in the polymer.json dependencies.

This polyfill is necessary for browsers which do not support web components.

Therefore until it is fixed it needs to be added manually...

After running 'polymer build':

1. open the app's bower_components folder
2. copy the webcomponentsjs folder
3. open the build folder
4. paste the webcomponentsjs folder in the bundled/bower_components and unbundled/bower_components
5. run firebase deploy

(Do this for all dependencies you require.)